# How to pass a build argument to `RUN --mount` like `RUN --mount=type=secret,id=key,uid=$USER_ID`?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to make a Dockerfile with a custom user ID, so that a user can match their user ID on the host system with that on the container. This has worked for me so far, until I found the need to mount a secret that that user could read... For the user to read the secret, you need to run something like `RUN --mount=type=secret,id=key,uid=1000 <command>`. But I don't want to hardcode the User ID. Unfortunately, if I declare a build arg `USER_ID` and attempt `RUN --mount=type=secret,id=key,uid=$USERID <command>`, it results in an error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 39: invalid value $USER_ID for uid
```

How can I mount with a variable uid, short of rewriting the Dockerfile every time I use it?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [nss_wrapper](https://cwrap.org/nss_wrapper.html) library, that might help

Comment: You probably don't want to "bake in" a specific host uid into an image; again, you'd have to rebuild the image every time a different user wants to run it.

Comment: the uid have to be an existing user of image,  If the host uid not exists in image, it also fail to read the secret. And the secret will be clean after image building done, you can't find it from container. So use any uid of image should be ok, why to use uid of host?

Comment: @yong The user was created in a previous line, though. It's convenient to use the uid of the host if you want to not have to change the permissions of the data volume.

Comment: Doesn't every image have a host uid baked into it?

Comment: Correct something,  the uid must exists in image, secondly must be the id of current  user to execute `RUN --mount=type=...`.  If not find better solution, you can replace the $uid in Dockerfile to real value, before run docker build cmd.